# Getting a selected row from an Arraylist in Android

Tags: android, arraylist, cursor

I have an arraylist populated with data from a cursor, I would like to get a selected or single record from this list which I would need to pass as an intent, how possible can I achieve this.

```
private ArrayList<Insect> insectList(){

    insects = new ArrayList<>();

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0){
        int count = 0;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            if (count < quizActivity.ANSWER_COUNT){
                count++;
                insect = new Insect(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BugsContract.BugsEntry.COLUMN_FRIENDLYNAME)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BugsContract.BugsEntry.COLUMN_SCIENTIFICNAME)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BugsContract.BugsEntry.COLUMN_SCIENTIFICNAME)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BugsContract.BugsEntry.COLUMN_IMAGEASSET)),
                Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BugsContract.BugsEntry.COLUMN_DANGERLEVEL)))
                );
                insects.add(insect);
                Collections.shuffle(insects);

            }
        }

    }

    return insects;
}
```

I need to get a selected record from the Arraylist insects

Comment: are you using recyler view or listview to display the data?

Comment: I need something like the position for each index of the arraylist insects

Comment: what do you mean by position?

Comment: @akshay_shahane, am using the Insects constructor to get the arraylist values for display but not in a recyclerview

Comment: i need to return a row from the arraylist

Comment: do you want to select particular record from database and pass it on to next activity?

Comment: something of that nature, let me give a better explanation. The insects arraylist return five records from the cursor database. Now I need to get a single record from this five records the arraylist have which would invariably be use as the selected row from the five records in the list

Comment: ok. but what is selection criteria?

Comment: name preferably or id. the value returned would be called this way        Insect [returned result].name  "returned result" is the result from the single selected record from the array list